# Getting wrong lengths in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a random animal generator, using lists of names, adjectives, bodyparts, origins, colors in text files. I want each description to have be justified (each line should have the same length as the others). Here is my code :

```
import time
import random
z=1
nom=open("ani_nom.txt").readlines()
adj=open("ani_adj.txt").readlines()
ori=open("ani_ori.txt").readlines()
cor=open("ani_cor.txt").readlines()
cou=open("ani_cou.txt").readlines()



for y in range (300):
    z=random.randint(2,24)
    Inom=[x for x in nom if len (x) == z ]
    Iadj=[x for x in adj if len (x) == z ]
    Iori=[x for x in ori if len (x) == z ]
    Icor=[x for x in cor if len (x) == z-2 ]
    Icou=[x for x in cou if len (x) == z ]
try:
        name = random.choice(Inom)
        adje = random.choice(Iadj)
        orig = random.choice(Iori)
        corp = random.choice(Icor)
        coul = random.choice(Icou)
except IndexError :
    continue

r = random.randint(0,4)
    print z
if r == 0:
    print name + adje
elif r == 1:
    print name + orig
elif r == 2:
    print name + "a " + corp + coul 
elif r == 3:
    print name + adje + "a " + corp + coul
elif r == 4:
    print name + orig + "a " + corp + coul
elif r == 5:
    print name + adje + orig + "a " + corp + coul
```

The problem is, Python seems to get wrong results when calculating the length of the string. I assured that there are no spaces left in my lists, but sometimes it count one more, or one less character than what there really is. When it is right (all the lines are same length), it always count one less, but it's not regular. How is this possible?

Comment: Did you take into account that a line break counts as well, even though it is not visible in an editor as a character?

Comment: Might it be because you're missing a row break at the end in some files?

Comment: You should provide representations for some of those strings. Call `repr` on strings that you think have the wrong length. Note that if you want justified strings, it's to pad them, e.g. using `str.ljust` or formatting.

Comment: I assume the row breaks are causing this. To fix it I changed my list files and separated my items with a comma instead of row breaks, and thus removed the readlines part when I open them. But now it doesn't seem to retrieve the substrings at all.

Comment: If you have trouble with line breaks, just do 'line.strip()'. This will remove any leading and trailing whitespace, including tabs and line breaks.

Comment: line.strip seems a good idea. Where exactly do I put it in my code ? In the list comprehension it seems to cause trouble. I get this : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: May I suggest you post your final code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, there is many improvements that can be done, and it will be a great source of learning for you.

Comment: Yes, I will do it. Thanks for the advice. However, I rather fix this lenght issue before posting it. the strip function doesn't seem to help much in the list comprehension either. Where should I apply it ?

Comment: @dogspeed Ideally, you do the `strip` when reading in the lines so that you actually store the stripped result (strings are *not* modified inplace). E.g., do `nom=[line.strip() for line in open("ani_nom.txt").readlines()]` when you read in data.

Comment: Allright, it's better but still not good. I just noticed something however. Since all my words are in french, there are accents like é and è, and it seems to correlate with the missing caracters. Does an é counts as 2 caracters ?

Comment: Yes, that was obviously it... Is there a way to avoid it and make the special letters such as é è ê î ï count as 1 caracter when retrieving the lenght ?